# Swift add key to local JSON for saving checkmarks

Tags: json, swift, swift4, checkmark

Im trying to save checkmarks in my application. But cause im paring my data from an api.. I don't know how I can add like the key "checked". The thing is the JSON gets downloaded once a Week, adding new content. Is there a way to still save my checkmarks?

```
struct Base : Codable {
    let expireDate : String
    let Week : [Weeks]
}

struct Weeks : Codable {
    let name : String
    let items : [Items]
}

struct Items : Codable {
    let Icon: String
    let text : String
}
```

In my RootTableView I have the array Weeks, and I would like to add checkmarks to the child tableView Items.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

```
  //
    //      Download JSON
    //
    enum Result<Value> {
        case success(Value)
        case failure(Error)
    }

    func getItems(for userId: Int, completion: ((Result<Base>) -> Void)?) {
        var urlComponents = URLComponents()
        urlComponents.scheme = "https"
        urlComponents.host = "api.jsonbin.io"
        print(NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0])

        let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]
        if preferredLanguage.starts(with: "de"){
            urlComponents.path = "/b/xyz"
        }
        else
        {
            urlComponents.path = "/xyz"
        }

        let userIdItem = URLQueryItem(name: "userId", value: "\(userId)")
        urlComponents.queryItems = [userIdItem]
        guard let url = urlComponents.url else { fatalError("Could not create URL from components") }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"


        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        config.httpAdditionalHeaders = [
        "secret-key": "xyzzy"
        ]

        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (responseData, response, responseError) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = responseError {
                    completion?(.failure(error))
                } else if let jsonDataItems = responseData {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                    do {
                        let items = try decoder.decode(Base.self, from: jsonDataItems)
                        completion?(.success(items))
                    } catch {
                        completion?(.failure(error))
                    }
                } else {
                    let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Data was not retrieved from request"]) as Error
                    completion?(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }


    func loadJson() {
        getItems(for: 1) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let item):
                self.saveItemsToDisk(items: item)
                self.defaults.set(item.expireDate, forKey: "LastUpdateItems")
            case .failure(let error):
            fatalError("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            self.getItemesFromDisk()
        }
    }

    //
    //      Save Json Local
    //

    func getDocumentsURL() -> URL {
        if let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            return url
        } else {
            fatalError("Could not retrieve documents directory")
        }
    }

    func saveItemsToDisk(items: Base) {
        // 1. Create a URL for documents-directory/items.json
        let url = getDocumentsURL().appendingPathComponent("items.json")
        // 2. Endcode our [Item] data to JSON Data
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(items)
            // 3. Write this data to the url specified in step 1
            try data.write(to: url, options: [])
        } catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func getItmesFromDisk(){
        // 1. Create a url for documents-directory/items.json
        let url = getDocumentsURL().appendingPathComponent("items.json")
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            // 2. Retrieve the data on the file in this path (if there is any)
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            // 3. Decode an array of items from this Data
            let items = try decoder.decode(Base.self, from: data)
            itemsDisk = items
        } catch {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you only get new weeks/items each week or do you download existing plus new data? I think that composition would be the way to go here but exactly how is hard to say without more info

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I download existing plus new  data.. thats the point

Comment: What kind of information you mean ?

Comment: So your goal then is to store the check mark locally for each item?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes

Comment: Your naming is pretty confusing. In terms of language semantics the struct is supposed to be named in singular form and the array variable in plural (and lowercased) form: `let weeks : [Week]`

Comment: nono I changed the names .. In my original code they are different. Sorry if I did some confusing things

Comment: How about add addition property in Base: like 'let checked:Bool?' and add value by the condition.

Comment: @RazibMollick But if I reload the data, they will be overwritten. They reload once a week

Comment: is there any unique field in Weeks /Items?

Comment: There is nothing unique like a number, but i could add that. The text is unique but this isnt the right thing

Answer (score 0):

I would create a wrapper class (or struct) for Items, say MyItem, that contains the original Items object and the checkmark property.

```
class MyItem {
    let item: Items
    var checkmark: Bool
    //more properties...?

    init(withItem item: Items {
        this.item = item  
        this.checkmark = false
    }

    func isEqual(otherItem item: Items) -> Bool {
        return this.item == item
    }
}
```

The isEqual is used to check if there already exists an MyItem object for a downloaded Items object or if a new should be created. isEqual assumes that you change the Items struct to implement the Equatable protocol.

You probably also need to replace Weeks but here you don't need to include the original Weeks object.

```
class MyWeek {
    let name: String
    let items: [MyItem]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what do you mean with "withItem" and "otherItem" sry Im relative new to swift.. And how can I implement the Equatable protocol..

Comment: I have given the parameter another name just to make the method call easier to read, `let newItem = MyItem(withItem: item)` .Equatable is a standard Swift protocol, [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable), you need to define what identifies an Items object to use it.

Comment: Ill give it a try tomorrow, Im not home at the moment. I will give you some feedback